# Android Custom Font issue

Tags: android, fonts

I am working on a android application. In this application, I am using Custom font (avenir_bold_font). I am using following method to set up font to buttons.

```
public static void setButtonFont(Activity activity, Button btnView, String fontType){
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"fonts/"+fontType);
    btnView.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Using above method am able to set up font to a button without any trouble. But in above method i have creating Typeface object every time any other calls it.

So i have made the changes in above method, I have converted Typeface local variable to Static variable so that it will improve performance, But The moment i created Typeface object as static , it does not work. it does not able to set up font

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using that does not work?

Comment: private static Typeface tf;
    public static void setButtonFont(Activity activity, Button btnView, String fontType){
        if(tf ==null){
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"fonts/"+fontType);
        }

        btnView.setTypeface(tf);
    }

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest creating a utility class that caches your loaded typefaces—something like the following:

```
public class TypefaceCache {
    private final static Map<String, Typeface> cache = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();

    private TypefaceCache() { /* do not allow instance creation */ }

    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String path){
        Typeface tf = cache.get(path);
        if (tf == null) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), path);
            cache.put(path, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Then inside `setButtonFont`, retrieve your typeface from the cache instead of creating it directly from assets each time:

```
public static void setButtonFont(Button btn, String fontType){
    btn.setTypeface(TypefaceCache.getTypeface(btn.getContext, "fonts/" + fontType));
}
```

(You don't need the `activity` parameter because the button has a reference to the context.)

**EDIT:** After thinking about this a bit, I would suggest the following version of the cache:

```
public class TypefaceCache {
    private final static Map<String, SoftReference<Typeface>> cache
        = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Typeface>>();

    private TypefaceCache() { /* do not allow instance creation */ }

    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String path){
        synchronized (cache) {
            final SoftReference<Typeface> ref = cache.get(path);
            Typeface tf = ref == null ? null : ref.get();
            if (tf == null) {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), path);
                cache.put(path, new SoftReference<Typeface>(tf));
            }
            return tf;
        }
    }
}
```

This has two improvements. First, it synchronizes on the `cache` object so that calls to `getTypeface()` are thread safe. (This may not be all that important if you are only going to call this method from the UI thread.) Second, it allows custom fonts to be garbage collected if the only reference to them is in the cache itself. With the original version I suggested, custom fonts would stay in memory for as long as the application process was alive, regardless of whether you still had a use for them.

Comment: Thank you very much, My problem is resolved , When I change the context from activity to button context, Now the static objects are working. However i did not investigate about how context change has resolved the problem.

Comment: @Vitthalk - Glad you got it working. You never said what was going wrong before (perhaps a `NullPointerException`?) but the code you posted in the comment looks to me like it should have worked as is, provided that a correct `activity` argument was passed in.

Comment: @TedHopp It just randomly occurred to me [where I read that the `Typeface` instances are cached](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Sharing_Between_Multiple_Threads) It must have bothered me in the back of my head. I was sure I read about it somewhere, but couldn't find any information on that subject :)

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - Yes, `Typeface.create(...)` can return a cached copy. That's not true of `createFromAsset(...)`. (You can see this in [the sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java): `createFromAsset` eventually returns the result of `new Typeface(nativeCreateFromArray(ptrArray))` (where `ptrArray` is an array of font family identifiers.)

Comment: @TedHopp indeed, thanks for clarifying and referencing the source!